# Two different notations for Heine-Borel property

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I have read two different usage for the expression "*Heine-Borel property*":

$1)$ Rudin: Functional Analysis (1.8 definition, page 9) (also in wikipedia):  
$X$ has the *Heine-Borel property* if every closed and bounded subset of $X$ is compact. (where $X$ denotes a topological vector space)

$2)$ Folland: Real Analysis (0.25 Theorem, page 15): 
*Heine-Borel property* means, that every open cover of $E$ has a finite subcover. (where $E$ denotes a subset of a metric space)

I know, the last one is how we define a compact space. My **question** is, which one is used in functional analysis, and what could be the point, that Folland used this notation in $2)$?

Comment: I think the first one is standard. I’ve never seen someone use the second one; maybe it’s historical?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$ 1) and 2) are equivalent. However, closed bounded subsets such as the unit ball in $\ell_\infty$ are not compact.